# Char* parse error from char array

Tags: c, arrays, json, char, readfile

I read a file and stock all characters like this:

```
void ReadFile()
{
    int c;
    FILE *file;

    int string_size;
    file = fopen("/userFiles/ex.txt", "r");
    char * content;
    if (file)
    {

        // Seek the last byte of the file
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        // Offset from the first to the last byte, or in other words, filesize
        string_size = ftell(file);
        // go back to the start of the file
        rewind(file);
        // Allocate a string that can hold it all
        content = malloc((string_size + 1) * sizeof(char));

        int i = 0;

        while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
        {
            //printf("%c",(char) c);
            content[i] = (char) c;
            i++;
        }

        content[string_size] = '\0';
        printf("content: %s",content);
        fclose(file);

    }
    else
    {
        printf("not load\n");
    }

}
```

Problem is if i read each carachter i've got the content of the file but if i do:

```
printf("content: %s",content);
```

I got just a symbol and not text whereas i need to pass the content var with correct text in argument of a json reply.

This is the first line of the file (CRC32):

> ## �ex.txt    k��X� ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?

Comment: It will not fix the problem probably, but use `fread()` instead of reading one character at a time. And `sizeof(char)` is ALWAYS 1, it's mandatory.

Comment: I've used fread but same problem

Comment: Where is your `printf()` call?

Comment: I've put it after add '\0' (edit)

Comment: I think your problem is the input file then. Because this code is fine.

Comment: Have you tried to use a *debugger* to see what is going on? Especially when you get `string_size`, inside `while` loop and to inspect content of `content` before printing.

Comment: The file is not a simple txt file, it looks like xml syntax but have a CRC32 at the begining, i add an example

Comment: The question marks are for non printable characters. The real binary values are needed to understand fully the problem.

You can try to pipe the output of your program into `hexdump -C`, this will show you what your program really outputs.

Comment: I've removed first line with CRC32 for test and file reading is fine, so just have this question, how read the special characters of CRC in the file ?

Comment: The problem is not the reading, but rather the way you output them. A possibility could be to check each byte value and print them with a '.' when they are not printable. That's somewhat similar to what hexdump -C would do.

`man ascii` can give you a starting step, but keep in mind that things like unicode can make the "printable" detection quite complex.

Answer (score -1):

I compiled and ran the following code and it shows no major problem when executed.

The compilable version I used is (cmdline: gcc main.c -Wall -Wextra -o main):

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main(void)
    {
            int c;
            FILE *file;

            int string_size;
            file = fopen("plop", "r");
            char * content;
            if (file == NULL)
            {
                    perror("fprintf");
                    return 1;
            }

            // Seek the last byte of the file
            fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
            // Offset from the first to the last byte, or in other words, filesize
            string_size = ftell(file);
            // go back to the start of the file
            rewind(file);
            // Allocate a string that can hold it all
            content = malloc((string_size + 1) * sizeof(char));

            int i = 0;

            while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
            {
                    //printf("%c",(char) c);
                    content[i] = (char) c;
                    i++;
            }

            content[string_size] = '\0';

            printf("content: %s", content);

            return 0;
    }
```

Maybe your file has a binary content?
What is the symbol printed, that you mentioned?

Comment: You are printing `content` when it's uninitialized, UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR.

Comment: My file contains a CRC32 at the begining so it has special characters, do you think thas this can be the cause ?

Comment: @user2622016: edited, but the same goes for the malloc not checked in the OP's original version...
---
to jof III: of course, for example, the special characters could contain a \r and some spaces and overwrite the rest of the output. Can you attach your file, for examination ?

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use quotes `""` around the content string:

```
printf("content: \"%s\"",content);
```

Comment: i did it, same problem